# Neuronal networks for Julia - first steps

Tags: neural-network, julia

I would like to use neuronal networks and related concepts with Julia. The idea is to start with Tic-Tac-Toe, then look at more general [m,n,k-games](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M,n,k-game). I would like to be flexible for experiments with different networks, size and number of hidden layers etc.

A simple way to represent the board is using an m * n matrix with +1, -1, 0 for “X”, “O”, “empty cell”. Therefore the network should have the m * n input layer, at least one hidden layer and the m * n output layer indicating the probability of the next move per cell.

I had a look at the available resources in https://juliapackages.com/c/ai

Which package do you propose to start with? What about ease of use and performance? (I don’t need a GPU backend)

Comment: Have you seen `AlphaZero.jl`?

Comment: No, I haven’t. Isn’t this overkill for the very beginning?

Comment: Almost certainly.